# How to correctly write a Unit-Tests in ABAP

Tags: unit-testing, abap

I need to write unit tests for my method. Here is the method itself:

```
METHOD set_pass_id.
    CLEAR mv_save_id_pass.
    mt_pass_id = mo_model->prep_id_pass(
        EXPORTING
          iv_vstel = iv_vstel ).

    mo_popup->call_0600( ).
    IF mv_save_id_pass = abap_true.
      zcl_test=>export_pass_id( iv_pass_id = zslo_vehicle_list_screen-zzpass_id ).
    ELSE.
      " Canceled by user
      MESSAGE e008(zlo_vehicle) INTO DATA(lv_mess).
      RAISE EXCEPTION TYPE zcx_common.
    ENDIF.
  ENDMETHOD.
```

This is how i wrote it.

```
METHOD set_pass_id.
    TRY .
        zslo_vehicle_list_screen-zzpass_id = '2'.
        mo_app->set_pass_id( iv_vstel = '4006' ).

        cl_abap_unit_assert=>assert_true(
          EXPORTING
            act = abap_true ).
        cl_abap_unit_assert=>assert_equals(
          EXPORTING
            act = zslo_vehicle_list_screen-zzpass_id
            exp = '2' ).

      CATCH zcx_common.
        cl_abap_unit_assert=>assert_equals(
            EXPORTING
              act = '008'
              exp = sy-msgno ).
    ENDTRY.
  ENDMETHOD.
```

The problem is that the coverage is not complete and I don't understand the correct way to cover the line `zcl_test=>export_pass_id( iv_pass_id = zslo_vehicle_list_screen-zzpass_id )` with tests.

Comment: What's the point of the line `cl_abap_unit_assert=>assert_true( EXPORTING act = abap_true ).`? Are you testing whether the ABAP runtime environment has its global constants set up correctly?!?

Comment: Hi! As I see this is a CLASS-METHOD. To which class does it belong? Normally this should be accessible to the test. What error does it throw?

Comment: @Kisbandi In tests, it immediately drops in the catch

Comment: Please create a dummy program for proposing a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It could be only a few lines long, and people would then be able to answer very precisely. Note that your question concerns the Test Doubles (whatever implementation is chosen), it doesn't concern specifically ABAP.

Answer (score 0):

The method has two branches:

1. `mv_save_id_pass = abap_true.`
2. `mv_save_id_pass = abap_false.`

If you want to achieve 100% test coverage, then you need tests that cover both branches of the method and confirm that the behavior of both branches is the expected behavior.

How do you do that? Well, that depends on how you set the value for `mv_save_id_pass`. How exactly that happens isn't apparent from the code you posted. But considered that the variable gets cleared in the first line of the method, it has to happen either in `mo_model->prep_id_pass` or in `mo_popup->call_0600`. Which means that the behavior of *this* class depends on the behavior of *another* class.

In such a case, the solution is to replace the object of that other class with a fake object that implements the same interface, but behaves the way the unit test requires. This is called a "[mock object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object)". A convenient way to create a mock object of a class without writing an entire own class is to use the [ABAP Test Double Framework](https://blogs.sap.com/2015/01/05/abap-test-double-framework-an-introduction/).

Now this of course begs the question how you inject that mock object into the object under test.

Neither `mo_model` nor `mo_popup` are initialized in that method, so they have to be initialized somewhere else. If the class creates those objects itself, then you might have to refactor it in a way that the creation of those objects happens outside of the class, and that the class then receives those dependencies. This principle is called "[Dependency Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)". It's a frequently used pattern to create code that is properly unit-testable. But it also has a lot of other advantages in regards to making OOP code more flexible and modular due to reduced coupling between classes. When you do that, then you can have your productive code inject the regular object and your tests inject a mock object that sets `mv_save_id_pass` to the value you need it to have for the test to achieve 100% coverage.

But if you really don't want to do such a radical refactoring of your code, then there is a more minimal adjustment you can make to enable dependency injection just for the purpose of unit tests: By adding a [`TEST-SEAM`](https://blogs.sap.com/2018/06/08/abap-test-seam-for-unit-test-with-external-dependencies-personal-guideline/) to the class you are testing. A test-seam is a point in the code under test that allows the unit testing framework to inject some code of it owns. This, for example, would allow you to replace the code that creates `mo_model` and/or `mo_popup` with code that creates mock objects instead.

Answer (score 0):

My interpretation is the problem is simply that you are not loading a value into the variable mv_save_id_pass.

It would be better to define it as a local variable, the mo_model->prep_id_pass method returns it and then you can check. Otherwise it will always remain abap_false and jump to the catch branch.

```
METHOD set_pass_id.
  mt_pass_id = mo_model->prep_id_pass(
      EXPORTING
        iv_vstel = iv_vstel
      IMPORTING
        ev_save_id_pass = DATA(mv_save_id_pass) ).
    
  mo_popup->call_0600( ).
  IF ev_save_id_pass = abap_true.
    zcl_test=>export_pass_id( iv_pass_id = zslo_vehicle_list_screen-zzpass_id ).
  ELSE.
    " Canceled by user
    MESSAGE e008(zlo_vehicle) INTO DATA(lv_mess).
    RAISE EXCEPTION TYPE zcx_common.
  ENDIF.
ENDMETHOD.
```

I defined it as EXPORTING parameter in my example, but it might be nicer to include it in the RETURNING value.